# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rdd'

Tags: python, pyspark

If the pk_col value is empty it should print NO PK defined. But I am getting this error. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rdd'.

```
pk_col = get_etl_mapping_data(etl_query = pk_col_qry).first()
if pk_col.rdd.isEmpty():
    pk_col = pk_col["pk"] 
    pk_col_list = pk_col.split(",")       
else:
    print("No PK Defined")
```

Comment: It is because `pk_col = get_etl_mapping_data(etl_query = pk_col_qry).first()` fails for some reason and `pk_col` is None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is a try block. This should work:

```
try:
    if pk_col.rdd.isEmpty():
        pk_col = pk_col["pk"] 
        pk_col_list = pk_col.split(",")       
except:
    print("No PK Defined")
```

If `pk_col` isn't defined, your if statement will throw an error which the except statement can handle.